# incorrect syntax near where but all the brackets are in the right places

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    [GMI Division#], [GMI Division],
    [Type_Mapping],
    SUM(Delv_EQC_Fctr) AS Delv_EQC_Fctr,
    SUM(Cuts_EQC_Fctr) AS Cuts_EQC_Fctr
FROM 
    (SELECT
         [GMI Division#], [GMI Division],
         [Type_Mapping], [Base Product#],
         SUM([BUoM_Delivery Quantity]) * ([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) AS Delv_EQC_Fctr,
         (SUM([BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total]) + SUM([BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total])) * ([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) AS Cuts_EQC_Fctr
     FROM
         [dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY]
     LEFT JOIN 
         [dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N] ON [dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY].[Base Product#] = CAST([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[BASPRD_NBR] AS BIGINT) 
     GROUP BY
         [GMI Division#], [GMI Division], [Type_Mapping], [Base Product#], 
         [EQC_FCTR], [BUoM_Delivery Quantity], [BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total], [BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total])
WHERE
    (([GMI Division#] IN (01, 03, 12, 16, 50)
      AND [Distribution channel] IN ('RT', 'ML')) OR 
     ([GMI Division#] IN (08) AND [Distribution channel] IN ('FS')))
    AND RIGHT([Fiscal Year/Period], 4) IN (2018)
GROUP BY 
    [GMI Division#], [GMI Division], [Type_Mapping], [EQC_FCTR]
```

This throws an error "incorrect syntax near where"

Comment: Derived tables need an alias in SQL Server.  You need to give the subquery a name.  You might start with `x` (before the `where`) while you think of a good name.

Answer (score 4):

Writing your code is the first part. You need to format it properly. Without that formatting, it is hard to read you.

This is a rewrite version of your query

```
WITH temp1 AS
(
  SELECT [GMI Division#],
  [GMI Division],[Type_Mapping],
  [Base Product#],
  SUM([BUoM_Delivery Quantity])*([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) AS Delv_EQC_Fctr,
  (SUM([BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total]) + SUM([BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total])) * ([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) AS Cuts_EQC_Fctr
  FROM [dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY] LEFT JOIN [dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N] ON
  [dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY].[Base Product#]=cast([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[BASPRD_NBR] as bigint) 
  GROUP BY 
  [GMI Division#],
  [GMI Division],
  [Type_Mapping],
  [Base Product#],
  [EQC_FCTR],
  [BUoM_Delivery Quantity],
  [BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total],
  [BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total]
)
SELECT [GMI Division#],[GMI Division],
        [Type_Mapping],Sum(Delv_EQC_Fctr) AS Delv_EQC_Fctr,
        Sum(Cuts_EQC_Fctr) AS Cuts_EQC_Fctr
FROM temp1        
WHERE (([GMI Division#] in (01,03,12,16,50) and 
([Distribution channel] IN ('RT','ML')) OR ([GMI Division#] in (08)) 
AND [Distribution channel] IN ('FS')))
AND  right([Fiscal Year/Period],4) IN (2018)
GROUP BY [GMI Division#],
        [GMI Division],
        [Type_Mapping],
        [EQC_FCTR]
```

I'm not sure where lies the problem with your `WHERE` clause.

To find the issue, I would operate that way.

1. Try to start with only one condition and see how it goes
2. If condition one is ok, add another one and etc

You have 4 conditions, it should be fast.

Best of luck

Update

---

There are website where you can format your code like this one -> http://www.sql-format.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to give it a temp name as following notice `MyTable`:

```
Select [GMI Division#],[GMI Division],[Type_Mapping],Sum(Delv_EQC_Fctr) as Delv_EQC_Fctr,Sum(Cuts_EQC_Fctr) as Cuts_EQC_Fctr
from (
select[GMI Division#],[GMI Division],[Type_Mapping],[Base Product#],Sum([BUoM_Delivery Quantity])*([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) as Delv_EQC_Fctr,
    (Sum([BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total])+Sum([BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total]))*([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) as Cuts_EQC_Fctr
    from[dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY]left join [dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N] on
    [dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY].[Base Product#]=cast([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[BASPRD_NBR] as bigint) 
    group by[GMI Division#],[GMI Division],[Type_Mapping],[Base Product#],[EQC_FCTR],[BUoM_Delivery Quantity],[BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total],[BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total]) MyTable
    where (([GMI Division#] in (01,03,12,16,50) and [Distribution channel]in ('RT','ML')) or([GMI Division#] in (08)and [Distribution channel]in ('FS')))
    and  right([Fiscal Year/Period],4) in (2018)
    group by [GMI Division#],[GMI Division],[Type_Mapping],[EQC_FCTR]
```

Comment: It still gives me an error stating invalid column names at various places at  distribution channel,fiscal Year/Period

Answer (score 0):

dose this work?

```
Select 
[GMI Division#]
,[GMI Division]
,[Type_Mapping]
,Sum(Delv_EQC_Fctr) as Delv_EQC_Fctr
,Sum(Cuts_EQC_Fctr) as Cuts_EQC_Fctr 
from ( 
    select
    [GMI Division#]
    ,[GMI Division]
    ,[Type_Mapping]
    ,[Base Product#]
    ,Sum([BUoM_Delivery Quantity])
        ,([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) as Delv_EQC_Fctr
    ,(Sum([BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total])+Sum([BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total]))
        ,([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[EQC_FCTR]) as Cuts_EQC_Fctr 
    from[dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY]
    left join [dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N] 
        on [dbo].[CF_Weekly_Casefill_Final_TY].[Base Product#]=cast([dbo].[CF_VEDW_PRD_MATL_DIM_N].[BASPRD_NBR] as bigint) 
    group by[GMI Division#]
    ,[GMI Division]
    ,[Type_Mapping]
    ,[Base Product#]
    ,[EQC_FCTR]
    ,[BUoM_Delivery Quantity]
    ,[BUoM_GMI Order Cut Total]
    ,[BUoM_GMI Delivery Cut Total]
    ) as tbl
    where (([GMI Division#] in (01,03,12,16,50)
    and [Distribution channel]in ('RT','ML')) 
    or([GMI Division#] in (08)and [Distribution channel]in ('FS'))) 
    and right([Fiscal Year/Period],4) in (2018) 
    group by [GMI Division#],[GMI Division],[Type_Mapping],[EQC_FCTR]
```

Comment: it still gives error stating invalid column names at distribution channel,fiscalyear/period,eqc_factor